# Searching through multiple directories in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, centos

I'm trying to figure out how I would search through multiple directories, defined with pushd, in order to find the disk space of the folders in the list, as well as whether any of the folders are sym links. Right now I have some very inefficient for loops that don't work over multiple directories (it works fine if there's just one, but once I start defining multiple working directories with pushd it mucks things up).

**UPDATE:**

Contents of $COMPARE for reference:

```
COMPARE=`comm -23 "$HOMEOUT" "$USEROUT" |
            comm -23 - <(
                for f in "${FILTER[@]}"; do
                    echo "$f"
                done | sort)`
```

Here's my code and my results when executing it:

```
DIRS=`ls -lah / | grep home | awk '{ print $9 }'`

 for i in "$DIRS"; do
    pushd /$i/ >/dev/null
 done

# Find the disk space of each folder

for x in "$DIRS"; do
        du -s /$x/$COMPARE | sort -n | cut -f 2-|xargs -i du -sh {}
done


# Check for and output symlinks
SYM=`for y in "$COMPARE"; do
    find /$DIRS/$y -maxdepth 1 -type l -print
done`
```

**Results:**

```
+ DIRS='home
home2
home3
old_home'
+ for i in '"$DIRS"'
+ pushd /home home2 home3 old_home/
+ for x in '"$DIRS"'
+ sort -n
+ du -s /home home2 home3 old_home/someuser someuser2 someuser3 someuser4
+ cut -f 2-
+ xargs -i du -sh '{}'
```

As you can see, this isn't working as I want it to search through each user in the list like so (depending on where their folder is located):

/home/user
/home/user2
/home2/user3
/home3/user4

Can someone suggest a better/more efficient way of doing this that actually works? I'd like to figure out how I can condense this, overall.

**Bash version:**

> GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release-(x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you pushing the directories on to the directory stack?. Also, there's no need to create a `DIRS` variable; just use `for i in /home/*; do`

Comment: It seemed like the best way to have multiple working directories in a bash script, as I want to search through any /home* directories found on the server. If that's not the case, I'm open to a better way to do it.

Comment: The directory stack merely makes it easier to switch to previously used working directories; there is only one working directory at a time. You never use the stack, as you never call `cd` or `popd`. However, you also never use the working directory, as you always pass the directory to search as an explicit argument to `du` and `find`.

Comment: You don't have to be in a directory in order to read it.

Comment: Next question: what is `$COMPARE`?

Comment: What's in `$COMPARE`? You use it as if it's a single directory in the `x` loop and as if it's a list of directories in the `y` loop?

Comment: Updated my question to add $COMPARE so you guys can reference that. It's a list of user directories that have already been filtered out with comm, which is where I ultimately get /home/user1 /home/user2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`"$DIRS"` will expand to `"home home2 ..."`, so `for` will see it as a single token. And don't parse `ls`, it's highly fragile. Use:

```
for x in /*home*; do
    du -sh "$x" | sort -h
done
```

(note that `sort -h` is a gnu extension, but as you're on redhat you should have it).
You haven't shown us how you construct `$COMPARE`, but I think you're looking for this instead of the second loop:

```
find /*home*/* -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

If you only want some users, you'll have to show us how you construct `$COMPARE`; you'll probably want to make it an array and use `find /*home*/"${COMPARE[@]}" ...`.

---

Construct `COMPARE` to be an array by wrapping it in `()`.

```
IFS=$'\n' COMPARE=($(comm -23 "$HOMEOUT" "$USEROUT" |
            comm -23 - <(printf "%s\n" "${FILTER[@]}" | sort))
```

and use it:

```
find /*home*/"${COMPARE[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

Comment: I updated my question so you have a clearer idea of what's happening with $COMPARE.

Comment: The IFS results in garbled paths in the results like so: /home/i' 'oforg - and the modified code in COMPARE doesn't quite work in my shell. Also, sort -h isn't recognized. I'm at least on the right track, though.

Comment: Your bash version says it's (at least compiled) on redhat. Is that actually your system?

Comment: @Striketh If your COMPARE contents don't have spaces, you can drop the IFS, but did you make sure to include the leading `$`, i.e. `$'\n'`, not `'\n'`?

Comment: I copied your code exactly as you put it, so it's all there. As soon as I try to use it, as is, I start getting syntax errors later on down in the script so something is off. Sort version is: sort (GNU coreutils) 5.97

Comment: That is an archaic version of sort (7 years old and 3 major releases back). What syntax errors are you getting?

Comment: It's the latest version in the CentOS repo for CentOS 5.9, unfortunately. Syntax errors are as follows: "test.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
test.sh: line 27: `for x in $DIRS; do'
test.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
test.sh: line 31: `done'}"